# Why is this javascript validation always failing

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a classic input validation for an email and a password, but for some reason my logic doesn't work and I can't figure out the part where it fails. This is code I've refactored from some one else and it bugging me quite a lot now

```
function Validation() {
  this.regex = {
    email: new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/),
    password: new RegExp(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{6,13}/),
  },
  this.email = function () {
    let valElement = document.getElementById("mail");
    console.log(valElement);
    let valueR = valElement.value.toString();
    console.log(valueR);
    let erorrEl = document.getElementById("error");

    let validate_mail = valueR.length == 0 && this.regex.email.test(valueR);
    console.log(validate_mail);
    console.log(this.regex.email);
    if(!validate_mail){
      valElement.className = "invalid";
      erorrEl.innerHTML = "Please enter a correct email";
      erorrEl.className = "error active"
      console.log("not validated email");
      event.preventDefault();
    }else{

      valElement.className = "valid";
      erorrEl.innerHTML = "";
      erorrEl.className = "error"
      console.log("validated email");
    }
  }
  this.password = function () {
    let valElement = document.getElementById("pass");
    let valueR = valElement.value;
    let erorrEl = document.getElementById("error2");
    let validate_pass = valueR.length == 0 && this.regex.password.test(valueR);
    if(!validate_pass){
      valElement.className = "invalid";
      erorrEl.innerHTML = "Please enter a correct password";
      erorrEl.className = "error active"
      console.log("not validated password");
      event.preventDefault();
    }else{
      valElement.className = "valid";
      erorrEl.innerHTML = "";
      erorrEl.className = "error"
      console.log("validated password");
    }
  }
  this.form = function(){
    if(this.password && this.email){

    }else{

    }
  }
}

var Valdator = new Validation();
        Valdator.email();
        Valdator.password();
```

Usually I'm calling these Valdator email and password functions in another file where it's a request from an API, but the idea is the same here, I don't think that woould make a difference

Comment: Did you mean to match the whole string? Use `^` at the start and `$` at the end of both patterns.

Comment: You don't need the `RegExp()` constructor for regular expression literals; you just need the `/literal regex/`

Comment: Also `valueR.length == 0 && this.regex.email.test(valueR)` will only succeed when the value is empty (0 characters long).

Comment: Protip: Don't use a regex to validate an email. If you already have it, like here, then it's fine, but it's way better to validate by just sending them a validation email.

Comment: @Pointy Dude, so it need to be valueR.length !== 0. Wow this was stupid on my side. Works fine now will refactor properly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RegEx is never being executed because `valueR.length == 0` will evaluate to `false`, which short-circuits your `&&` before it can execute the second part. Remember that if you are AND-ing two statements and the first statements evaluates to `false`, there is no need to evaluate the second statement because both `false && true` and `false && false` evaluate to `false`.

That being said, it makes no sense to check for `valueR.length == 0` as a pre-condition for evaluating a RegEx on `valueR` - why would we run an RegEx on a 0-length string? You should flip this logic to `!==`.

And please always use `===` or `!==` in the future, as `==` gets messy with type conversion.

```
let validate_pass = valueR.length !== 0 && this.regex.password.test(valueR);
```

Comment: @AngelVasilev great to hear! Please mark this answer as accepted if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: yeah I just did, it made me wait 4 minutes until I could. Have a nice day/night

Comment: @AngelVasilev happy to help, weird that it made you wait, but I guess that's SO's way of doing things. Happy coding!